# Change multiple elements style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the style of multiple buttons with JavaScript.

I tried giving them all an ID and change it this way:

```
document.getElementById('button').style.color = "#ff0000";
```

But this of course only changed the first.

I could give them all different IDs but there are over 150 of them and that would get cumbersome.

How can I change them all?

Comment: Well you have to use different IDs. Or, give them all a class.

Comment: You can't have multiple identical IDs.  Give them a class, and then apply the change to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common class name to all buttons and apply text styles as shown in code below.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```

Or give a common class name to all buttons and apply the styles using css.

```
.btn{
   color : #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".ecard");
```

- Using above we can call to all the elements with class = "ecard".
- "querySelectorAll" can select many elements at once.
- Replace "selector" with any term you like.
- Replace "ecard" with the ID or CLASS of respective set of elements.

Note : We use "#" in front of a term if it is ID, and "." in front of a term if it is CLASS.

```
for (let index = 0; index < ec.length; index++) {
        const ecc = selector[index];
        ecc.style.backgroundColor = "#10141E"
    }
```

Using above code we create a loop which end after changing the background color of all the elements. In here javascript only runs above if the respective number of elements set of elements should greater than 0

- Replace "selector" terms on above code, with term you used to replace    term :
  selector, in first code I mentioned
- Replace "ecc" with any    term you like., and use that term to change
  style of multiple element

Thanks !